# Python Insertion Sort Confusion

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have this code:

```
Array = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

for c in range(1, len(Array)):
     if(Array[c]==-1):
         continue
     temp = Array[c]
     i = c
     d = c-1
     while(d>=0):
        if(Array[d]==-1):
            d-=1
            continue
        if(temp>=Array[d]):
            break
        Array[i] = Array[d]
        i = d
        d-=1
     Array[i] = temp
```

When I run the code as written, the final Array is:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

However, when I change the last line to "Array[i] = Array[c]" instead of "Array[i] = temp", the final Array is:

```
[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

This doesn't make sense to me.  If "temp" IS Array[c], why does changing that line make this difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`temp` gets the value of `Array[c]`, but then the storage location `Array[c]` is overwritten with another value by the first execution of `Array[i] = Array[d]` (since `i==c` initially). `temp` is there to *preserve* the initial value so you can use it later on, even though `Array[c]` itself has been reset.

Comment: Oh, duh.  I knew it was something simple I just wasn't catching.  Thanks!